# Comparing a JButton color

Tags: jbutton

Im creating a pairing game and I set random colors to array of JButtons, Is there a way on how do I compare the color of the first randomed color JButtons to the colors of second Array of JButtons?

Comment: have you tried to compare the `int` value of the color..? btn.getBackground().getRGB()==anotherColorIntValue

Comment: Solved the problem, I've converted the color to String and make it the ActionCommand of the button, By the way, thank you @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 for the suggestion :)